# When using Joomla\CMS\Http\Http to do a request, how to check timeout?

Tags: joomla-3.9

In a component, I'm using the call to retrieve an xml file hosted on a website .  However, in some cases, the firewall blocks this kind of request so there is no answer. In this case, how can I check for a timeout? This is my code:

```
$url = 'https://mysite.org/filetoretrieve.xml';

$options = new Joomla\Registry\Registry;

try
{
    $transport = new Joomla\CMS\Http\Transport\StreamTransport($options);
}
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    $this->app->enqueueMessage($e->getMessage(), 'error');

    return false;
}

if (!$transport->isSupported())
{
    return false;
}

// Create a 'stream' transport.
$http = new Joomla\CMS\Http\Http($options, $transport);

try
{
    $response = $http->get($url);
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    $this->app->enqueueMessage($e->getMessage(), 'error');

    return false;
}

if ($response->code == '200')
{
    // Handling the answer here
}
```

Comment: You can check if the URL exist with a little script I wrote. https://gist.github.com/Llewellynvdm/4c78638b418f641e7bae1e844be5acf4

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to check specifically for a timeout. Timeout acts as a connection failure and results in an exception being thrown when calling `$http->get($url)`. Which you are already catching.